# Hashicorp-vault userpass authentication

Tags: amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use Hashicorp vault for storing secrets for service accounts username and passwords --- I am following this link https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html to create the user name and password.

My question here is that here as per this example I am specifying the password "foo" when i curl this from any ec2 instances, as part of automations, so we want to automated this and codes will come from git: 
     `curl \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"password": "foo"}' \
    http://10.10.218.10:8200/v1/auth/userpass/login/mitchellh`

Our policy is that we should NOT store any password in git... How do I run this curl and get authenticated to vault without specify the password for the user? is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to use [aws-auth-method](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws.html#aws-auth-method)?

Also, if you are sure to want to use password authentication I think you can do something like this:

- Generate user/password in the Vault, store user passwords in the Vault and set a policy to allow reading specific user password for specific ec2-instance ([EC2 auth method](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws.html#ec2-auth-method));
- In the ec2-instance run consul-template which will authenticate in the Vault with an ec2-instance role;
- This consul-template will generate curl command with specific user name and password
- Use this command